# Small embedded synthesized speech libraries/suggestions

Tags: embedded, speech

Are there any easy-to-use free or cheap speech synthesis libraries for PIC and/or ARM embedded systems where code size is more important than speech quality?  Nowadays it seems that a 1 meg package is considered "compact", but a lot of microcontrollers are smaller than that.  Back in the 1980's Apple hired a contractor to produce Macintalk, which offered reasonable-quality speech in a 26K package which ran on a 7.16MHz 68000, and a program called SAM could produce speech that wasn't quite as good, but still serviceable, with a 16K package that ran on a 1MHz 6502.  The SpeakJet runs a speech-synthesis algorithm on some type of PIC.

I probably wouldn't particularly need to produce speech, but would want to be able to speak messages formed from a number of pre-set words.  Obviously it would be possible to simply prerecord all the messages, but with a vocabulary of e.g. 100 words, I would think that storing 16K worth of code plus maybe 1K worth of phonetic strings would be more compact than storing audio for 100 words.

Alternatively, if I wanted to store audio for 100 words, what would be the best way of generating a set of words that would flow naturally together?  On older-style speech synthesizers, any given word could be spoken three ways: neutral inflection, falling inflection (as if followed by a period), or rising inflection (followed by a question mark).  Words with neutral inflection could be spliced together in any order and sound fine.  The text-to-wave tools I've found, though, seem to like to add finer details of inflection which sound "off" if words are cut apart and resequenced.  Are there any tools which are designed for producing waves that can be concatenated and spliced nicely?  If I do use such a tool, what audio format would be best for storing the waves so as to allow efficient decoding on a small microcontroller?

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/TTSInCore/TTS_Comparison.pdf) has a comparison of flite and eSpeak - eSpeak appears to be around 500kB but you don't actually mention what size constraint you need. The Mac and SAM stuff you mentioned seems to have been done by [SofVoice Inc](http://www.text2speech.com/).

Comment: I hadn't realized the same company did SAM and MacinTalk; interesting.  I didn't specify the particular size constraints because they're a bit flexible, but I'd been hoping for something along the lines of what was achievable 25 years ago.  An ARM might not have the code density of a 68000, but I would think it should be able to give results comparable to what the 68000 achieved in 1984, without needing too much more memory than the 68000 did.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did this I was able add hardware like:http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9578 . There may be patent liabilities in your environment, like I ran into, that force a commercial software stack or OTS chip.

Otherwise, I've used http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/ for more lenient projects, and it worked well.